# Reset / unbind change event from select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have that submit button which prints the current value of select. To prevent printing values before any option is selected, i added an `on.change` event to make sure at least one option is selected.

The problem is that select's content is not static. It can be replaced. Thats why i would like to repeat the process (unbind old change event, add new one), before any new values are printed. If i dont do this, some old values that are no longer avaliable might print.

i tried with:

```
$('#smth').off('change');
```

but it doesnt work. Button can be pressed even though i removed the event.

**Code:**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" value="reset" id="reset" />
<input type="submit" value="change val" id="chv"/>
<br/><br/>
<select id="smth">
    <option selected="1" disabled="1">Choose</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#smth').on('change',function() {

    $('#sub').on('click', function() {

        $('#container').text($('#smth').val());

    });

});

$('#chv').one('click', function() {

    $('#smth').html('<option selected="1" disabled="1">Choose</option><option>test</option>');

});

$('#reset').on('click',function(){
    $('#smth').off('change');
});
```

**FIDDLE EXAMPLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/JgxFA/1/

Comment: You're removing the `select element`'s change event, not the `button` click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unbind the embedded #sub click handler as well.

```
$('#reset').on('click',function(){
    $('#sub').off('click');
    $('#smth').off('change');
});
```

Comment: +1, but i had to wrap both inside another event, otherwise it doesnt work anymore after i unbind them.